# What bosses drop sigils?

Tags: warframe

Is it just the mini-bosses, like the Stalker, G3, Zanuka? Is it actual bosses, like the boss nodes on each planet, is it the mini bosses, like VIP targets and the ones in Orokin Sabotage missions? Is it Vor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Sigils

Based on the wiki it currently seems like only Assassins drop sigils:

> Assassins like the Stalker, The Grustrag Three and Zanuka Hunter can
>   also drop their own Sigil designs, and Founders have access to their
>   own exclusive Sigils. These Sigils however are purely cosmetic, and do
>   not contribute to Syndicate Standing.